My sql query does not return results when I use a WHERE id = something, thought the value provided is not NULL or zero
PHP and MySQL
Hello,
I have a MySQL table called “weddings”, containing “id” – int, primary key, Auto_increment, “male_name”, “female_name”, “year” and “file” (PDF file name containing the wed certificate)
I have a form with checkboxes for each wed from the table. Each checkbox has the record id as “id” and the record’s filename(e.g. filename.pdf) as it’s value. The user selects which wed one wants to delete (delete the record from the table and the PDF file from the server – which is constructed like “filename_recordID.pdf”  (for the record with id 5, the file name from DB and from server is filename_5.pdf)
What works:
The data from the form is retrieved ok. The delete is ok (for the record in the DB and for the file on the server).
What doesn’t work:
I want to display for the user the female_name and the male_name for the record that the file on the server had an error when deleting (I have 2 PDF that have errors and I use them as tests everytime for this). Aditionally, I want to display an error code: for the undeleted files from server, the error code will be “filename_without_extension_SRV”. (for the record with id 10, it will look like “wed_10_SRV”)
-> The fail is that female_name, male_name and file name are not displayed. No error, just empty. They are not displayed.
(I will do the same with records that cannot delete from DB, if case: display for the user the female_name and the male_name and the error code, for the record with id 10, it will look like “wed_10_DB”)
Each file (on the server and the name in the DB will be like: wed_<wed_id>.pdf (my php script modifies like this each uploaded file)
undeleted_weds_serv = Array containing the IDs of the records that were undeleted from the server (the corresponding PDF file didn’t delete on the server)
length_undeleted_serv = length of the Array
undeleted_weds_serv Array contains the records ids of the weds that their file couldn’t be erased from the server and contains 0 for the weds that deleted successfully from the server (the PDF file of the wed)
The Array and the length are constructed ok (I echoed the Array and it’s length and it’s constructed ok).
My code below:
//foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) - looping through the $_GET array (data is getting ok)
    

foreach ($_GET as $id_casat => $fisier) {
//1. deleting the file from the server
    
// Path to the directory containing files
$directory_path = '../../Continut_site/Primaria/Birouri/Evidenta_persoane/publicatii_casatorie/2024_teste';
    
// Full path to the file
$file_path = $directory_path . '/' . $fisier;
    
// Check if the file exists on the server and delete it
    
if (unlink($file_path)) {
    //array containing the IDs 
    $casatorii_Sterse_serv[] = $wed_id;
                 
    //array containing the IDs of the weds whose files were NOT deleted from the server (due to possible error)
    $undeleted_weds_serv[] = 0;
} else {
   
    $undeleted_weds_serv[] = $wed_id;
}
             
//END deleting file from the server 
             
//2. deleting the file from the DB   

$sql = "DELETE FROM weddings WHERE id = $wed_id";
             
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    //echo "Record deleted successfully";
            
    //array containing the ids of the deleted weds (from the DB)
    $db_deleted_weds[] = $wed_id;
            
    //array containing the ids of the UNDELETED weds (from the DB)
    $db_undeleted_weds[] = 0;
} else {
    //array containing the ids of the UNDELETED weds (from the DB)
    $db_undeleted_weds[] = $wed_id;
}
         
//END deleting the file from the DB 
             
}//end FOREACH (loop through $_GET array)       
        
//length of the array containing the ids of the records that their corresponding files were deleted from server - OK
$length_undeleted_serv = count($undeleted_weds_serv); 
        
        
//echo "length_undeleted_serv: $length_undeleted_serv - OK";
//echo "length_deleted_serv: $length_deleted_serv - OK";
        
for($i=0; $i < $length_undeleted_serv; $i++){
    //echo "(serv) $undeleted_weds_serv[$i]<br>";
    if($undeleted_weds_serv[$i]){
        echo "(nesters serv) ".$undeleted_weds_serv[$i]."<br>";
            
        $sql_undeleted_weds_serv = "SELECT * FROM `weddings` WHERE `id` = '$undeleted_weds_serv[$i]'";
    
        $result_undeleted_weds_serv = mysqli_query($con, $sql_undeleted_weds_serv);
                  
        //cauta in BD numele persoanelor nesterse pentru afisare
        while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result_undeleted_weds_serv)){
            $male_name = $record['male_name'];
            $female_name = $record['female_name'];
            $db_file = $record['fis']; //file name from the BD (it exists on the server with the same name)
            
            // Remove the extension of the file (use it's name as an error code displayed at the user)
            $filename_without_ext = substr($db_file, 0, strrpos($db_file, "."));
            
            //end remove file extension
            
            echo "<br><br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;❌ An error occured in <i>".$male_name."</i> și <i>".$female_name."</i> <font color='#f26b1e'> &#8658; "." Error code: <b>".$filename_without_ext."_SRV"."</b></font>"."⚠️";
            
        }//end WHILE    
        
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result_undeleted_weds_serv) > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_undeleted_weds_serv)) {
                echo "id: " . $row["id"] . " - Name: " . $row["name"] . "<br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }   
    }else{
        echo "<br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;✅ Was deleted <i>".$male_name."</i> și <i>".$female_name."</i> (".$db_file.") <br><br>";
    }//end if_1     
}//end FOR looping through the Array 


Your script is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attack. Even if you are escaping variables, its not safe! You should always use prepared statements and parameterized queries in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

When iterating over an array, the code is usually clearer if you use foreach instead of for.

Today is International Apostrophe Day, so it's a good day to learn the difference between "it's" and "its".

In your What doesn't work section you say what you want to do, but don't say how it's failing. What is your question?

Where is the beginning of //end FOREACH (loop through $_GET array)?

You're deleting the row from the DB even when deleting the file fails. So you won't be able to display the names after that. Either skip deleting the database row, or get the names before you delete.

@Barmar I try to display the names for the rows that couldn't be deleted (the record is still there). I try to display those rows using WHERE record_id = ids from the Array containing the ids of undeleted rows :/

Why would any of the row deletions fail?

$undeleted_weds_serv is the array of files that couldn't be deleted, not rows that couldn't be deleted.

The failed row deletions are in $db_undeleted_weds. All the code that uses that is commented out.

@Barmar The deletion is ok for all the records by now; I have 2 pdf files (on the server) that corresp. to 2 rows. They are not being deleted from the server (only those 2 pdf files - they seem to have some errors - but I use them to check of the correct error messages I display). After those files not being deleted from the server, I want to display for the user (from their corresp. records) which are the names of the persons for which delete had errors because there is no use to display the name of the files to the user. undeleted_weds_serv - array containing the ids of the records undel.

@Barmar failed row deletions - I deleted the comment containing it now because I am not dealing with the failed rows for now, only with the failed file deletions from server (until now, all the rows are being deleted ok)

And that's the problem. You're deleting the rows, then you're trying to select them to get the male and female names. But they're gone now.

@Barmar You are right! I'll save the input into an array to keep their names. Best wishes! *_-
